# Wordpress query_posts multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Does anyone know if it is possible to have multiple arrays within query_posts if so how?

I'm looking to query posts that are in category 1 & 2. But also posts that are in 1 & 3 and 1 & 4.

So the posts MUST be in category 1 as well as one of the other categories.

So the category__and would be where I've started which allows me to query posts both in 1 & 2 but how would I then progress to add the others 3,4 etc? as adding them 1,2,3,4,5 will only show posts in all 5 categories correct?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php                                   
    query_posts( 
        array( 'category__and' => array(1,2), 
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
              ) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
?>
```

Is it possible to put an array of arrays to perform what I have asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with the tax_query parameter.

```
query_posts(
    array(
        posts_per_page => 5,
        tax_query => array(
            relation => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( 1, 2 ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( 1, 3 ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( 1, 4 ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

See the documentation for any additional details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Hi that's great, will that show posts that are in both 1 & 2 not just posts that are in 1.